# SVN and SFTP synchronisation with eclipse

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, svn

I have to create and configure an eclipse (Mars 2) for a C project. The project is on a SVN repository, and can only be compiled on a specific linux redhat server that has the appropriate toolchain.

What I need is an IDE that would allow me to commit my changes to the repository and that would automagically synchronize them on the Linux server. I tried a few things but none of them worked. I must (to my great regret) avoid the need of a terminal while using that IDE, but of course not while configuring it.

Firstly, I used the Remote System Explorer feature in eclipse. I connected succefully to the server, created a "Remote Project" that I could open in the C/C++ perspective. However, the whole thing is impossible to use, as it has no indexation, I had to create "User Actions" in order to compile (which is on my point of vue pretty anti-ergonomic) and the SVN plugin does not detect the project as an SVN copy. Furthermore, in the C/C++ perspective, there is a 2s gap between the moment I type something, and the moment it appears on my screen.

I also tryed to mount a network filesystem on my local machine, with sshfs, and if it works far better, I still experience lags. Also, I had to write a Makefile and call my compiler via "ssh $(USER)@$(HOST) build.ksh". (one of the point of the projetc is to write a real Makefile...). But SVN is working.

I also tried to run eclipse on the host machine, with X forwarding, and if it works perfectly, there is still lags...

Finally, I tried an sftp synchronisation, but it seems I can't use my SVN plugin features and the sftp together.

I am out of solutions, and pretty frustrated as I feel that this kind of things should be pretty easy. I mean, all I want is that eclipse automatically copy my files on my remote home directory... Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 0):

To me this sounds like a perfect use-case for a continuus integration (CI) system. Generally speaking, this CI system pulls the code from your repository (for example in regular intervals) and then executes the build chain, collects artifacts, informs you about the state of your build, etc.

Although it originated from the Java world, I have successfully used Jenkins for continuus integration of C-projects on a Linux server, but there are others, like TeamCity or GitLab CI (the latter would require you to switch to Git, but it's a really neat system with a YAML configuration for CI).

Of course CI systems have a learning curve - you don't something like a free meal - but it may really be worth the effort.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have such power on the project I am working on... CI is a planned change, but not for now... Furthermore, I would like to be able to compile my work on the remote machine, and to do basic tests before commiting it, and I am not sure CI tools are designed for that...

Comment: I see, but how does it come that you can't install the build chain locally?

Comment: I need the oracle pro*C precompiler, and it is not possible to install it for every developer, as some of us are on windows or linux, we don't all have administration privileges, and as I heard, a ton of configuration files and database description files are needed... too complicated, I think.